# Android - SQL query every 1 second for 2 minutes

Tags: android, mysql, runnable

I'm trying to check a record of a database in real time.
For this, I intend to check every 1 second every 2 minutes.
I've been trying to do the consultations.

The query do with the volley, which maybe it's the most convenient. The problem is that it seems not work the query sequence.

Here my code:

```
public void SQLQuery(final String hash) {
    Handler h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int time = 1;
            while (time <= 120) {
                if (!isAccepted) {
                    try {
                        makeRequestAgain(hash);
                        time++;
                        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(time));
                        pDialog.setMessage("Segundos restantes: " + time);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    hidePDialog();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Autorización denegada o tiempo de espera agotado.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }, 120000);
}

public void makeRequestAgain(final String hash) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, PrepareData.CHECK_REQUEST,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(final String response) {
                    if (response.equalsIgnoreCase(PrepareData.USER_ACCEPT)) {
                        //
                        //El user acepto -> OK -> Intent MAP
                        isAccepted = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Autorización OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Todavia no acepta...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Se perdió la conexión con el servidor.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(PrepareData.ID_CONSULTA, hash);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

[image]

Directly, I do not get the message log and the progress dialog is not updated.

What I will be failing?

Thanks in advice.

**Edit:**

Permissions are OK in the manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I use this same "makeRequestAgain()" in other .java and run fine, all the request are good, but, this particulary request, doesn't work,.

Comment: Please add more information, such as Permissions in AndroidManifest, the HTTP response of requests made, and the Android version you are executing this (looks like `M`)

Comment: Added. I'm working in Android 6.0.0 (API 23).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can go with `Thread`. `Handler` or `AsyncTask` uses `Thread` internally. So go with `Thread`.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){ ... });
t.start();
```

So if you want to create a new instant of thread to run again, may be in a loop,

```
new Thread(t).start();
```

because thread once become a daemon cannot be started again.

Inside the runnable, if you want to update a UI element, you have to do it with `runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){...});`. Call it inside the Runnable which is in turn inside a `Thread`.

Comment: @Ferrrmolina sure if you have trouble, lemme know

Comment: Work, partially, but your recommend seems work :). Thanks

Comment: @Ferrrmolina I am working on a full solution, just gimme some time . :)

Comment: The SQL query and timer, work fine: http://prntscr.com/aydryf Now i wish to show the timer in the progress dialog, is this possible, i guess its possible, i'll try. BTW thanks for your time.

Comment: @Ferrrmolina Thats why I updated that as soon as I posted. However happy to know it works 

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `requestQueue.start()` before adding requests.

Also, I recommend using a single `RequestQueue` instance, and waiting for a request to finish before starting a new one.

Also, not sure what this has to do with SQL. Volley is an HTTP library.

Comment: Ok, i tryed adding requestQueue.start(), but no work. How can waiting for a request to finish before starting a new one?, can you explain a little more please?. I make the Query in a php file, with volley, i send a post request and i check if response are == to a String

Comment: You can make the next request from within the `StringRequest` callback.